# How do I remove text in the body of an email before send?

Tags: vba, outlook

Our company puts a notice on any incoming email from an outside source to warn us to exercise caution when opening attachments or clicking on links. Warranted? Yes. Annoying? Yes. Looks somewhat unprofessional? Maybe.

I've tried several different iterations of VBA to ask if I want the message removed on send. My current code is below and it will bring up the message box, so I know that my formatting is correct and it finds the text, but it won't actually remove it.

```
Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
Dim strBody As String

If InStr(Item.Body, "NOTICE: This email is from an external sender. Please exercise caution when opening attachments or clicking links.") > 0 Then
   If MsgBox("Do you want to remove the Notice?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
     strBody = Replace(Item.Body, "NOTICE: This email is from an external sender. Please exercise caution when opening attachments or clicking links.", "", vbTextCompare)

   Else
      strBody = Item.Body
   End If
End If

Item.Save
End Sub
```

I would like for the message box to come up and ask if the notice needs to be removed and then remove it if I click yes, but leave everything else in the email alone. One caveat is that there could be multiple instances of this notice if it's a long chain with multiple replies. If I'm the only one on the chain then my macro will have removed any in prior replies, but if others are on the chain and don't remove theirs then I'd like my macro to do it if I reply (I realize I can't do anything about others).

Would the code need to be any different if it's an HTML email versus plain text?

EDIT: Here's my current code. I've got it to remove the notice and it now will not delete a new email, but the send on a reply is really slow.

```
Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)

Dim strBody As String

If InStr(Item.HTMLBody, "LHMSE NOTICE: This email is from an external sender. Please exercise caution when opening attachments or clicking links.") > 0 Then
   If MsgBox("Do you want to remove the LHMSE Notice?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
     strBody = Replace(Item.HTMLBody, "LHMSE NOTICE: This email is from an external sender. Please exercise caution when opening attachments or clicking links.", "", vbTextCompare)
     Item.HTMLBody = strBody

   Else
      strBody = Item.HTMLBody
   End If
End If

Item.Save
End Sub
```

Comment: An email can have three bodies: a text body, an Html body and a RTF body. I have never seen a RTF body so I cannot comment on them. If there are both text and Html bodies, there is nothing the user can do to see the text body although a VBA macro can access either.  It is years since I have coded anything in this area and that was with an ancient version of Outlook so I could be out-of-date and or forgetful.  My recollection is that changing the text body did not change the Html body.  If that is still true, your code will not change what you see on the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never set the `Item.Body` property back with the new value stored in the `strBody` variable. Also keep in mind that you will wipe out the formatting since you are dealing with the plain text body rather than `MailItem.HTMLBody`.

Comment: Thank you! One more question though, it looks like my macro now keeps the spell check from running. Is there a way that I can bring that back in?

Comment: Sorry, I jumped the gun. The spell check does run.

Comment: Looks like I jumped the gun again. The script that I have now deletes the body in a new email as well as removing the notice in a reply or forward. Is there a way I can have it only remove the notice regardless of a new, reply, or forward?

Comment: Sorry about that. I've edited my original since the comment is too short for it.

Comment: That looks fine to me - it should work for both new emails as well as replies/forwards.Are you asking how to do this only for replies?

Comment: That's the thing, it doesn't work. I'm hoping to get it to work for replies and forwards, but not erase any new emails (it was doing this when I had `Item.HTMLBody = strBody` just before `Item.Save`. Now when I moved it, it doesn't do anything.

Comment: So what exactly fails? Your script does not run at all? Or it does nothing? Have you tried to debug it and step through line by line?

Comment: It doesn't seem to do anything at all now. I'd like to try the debug and step into it, but I can't get that to work. I'm somewhat familiar with VBA in excel and know how to step into that, but it's not working as I expected in outlook.