# How to delete a phrase from email?

Tags: vba, outlook

I'd like to remove the following phrase from the beginning of every email from sources other than a specific domain:

"This is an EXTERNAL email. Do not click links or open attachments unless you validate the sender and know the content is safe."

I am trying to delete this phrase from each email.

I grabbed some code online from another person trying to do something similar.

```
Sub Del()

Dim Ins As Outlook.Inspector
Dim Document As Word.Document
Dim Word As Word.Application
Dim Selection As Word.Selection

Set Ins = Application.ActiveInspector
Set Document = Ins.WordEditor
Set Word = Document.Application
Set Selection = Word.Selection

Dim search As String
search = "This is an EXTERNAL email. Do not click links or open attachments unless you validate the sender and know the content is safe."

Dim para As Paragraph
For Each para In Document.Paragraphs

    Dim txt As String
    txt = para.Range.Text

    If InStr(txt, search) Then
        para.Range.Delete
    End If

Next

End Sub
```

I get

> Run-time error '91'

on line 9 `Set Document`.

Comment: I am not familiar with the Word Editor but, if I was, I doubt I would attempt to use it for this type of edit.  VBA string manipulation will be easier.  However, before you can edit an HTML body you need to make sure you know what it is.  If there is any formatting within the string, your Find will not work.  Try [My full diagnostic routine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58000707/973283) to discover exactly what is within the body.  Is it always the same string?  Probably yes.  In which case a simple replace should do the trick.

Comment: Once you know what to remove, look at the entire question to which _My full diagnostic routine_ was a part answer.  This was a similar problem to yours so reading the question and the full answer will be helpful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I remove text in the body of an email before send?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54654942/how-do-i-remove-text-in-the-body-of-an-email-before-send)

Answer (score 0):

that works a lot easier within Outlook:

```
sub delete_part_of_text()

  Dim search As String
  search = "This is an EXTERNAL email. Do not click links or open attachments unless you validate the sender and know the content is safe."

  If Not TypeOf Item Is mailitem Then Exit Sub
  Item.HTMLBody = Replace(Item.HTMLBody, search, "")
end sub
```

of course you have to adapt this - should this run automatically on each incoming mail oder are you going to call this when needed for one/some mails? That changes the call of the procedure, but the princip abobe works.

Max